# z index not working properly when transform used

Tags: html, css

I want to absolutely position child element below the parent element. I used z-index: -1; to do that. But when I use transform on the parent I can no longer put child element below the parent. I did some research and found that it is because transform is creating new stacking context. I don't know how to solve this. please help.

```
 <style>
      .container {
        width: 1000px;
        height: 500px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        background-color: green;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }

      .container::after {
        content: "";
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
        background-color: orangered;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -10%;
        left: -10%;
        z-index: -1;
      }
 </style>
 <div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding a wrapper to your container:

```
  <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```

and add the transform to the wrapper:

```
    .wrapper {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    }
  .container {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: green;
  }

  .container::before {
    content: "";
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: orangered;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10%;
    left: -10%;
    z-index: -1;
  }
</style>
```

but generally you should not use transform and instead use flexbox or grid:

flexbox explained:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

grid explained:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/